# Angular 2 - Create Section[in Html] on button click for n times

Tags: angular, typescript, append

```
  <div class="schedule-time">
      <span>Add Schedule Time <span class="adr" (click)="AddNewSchedule()">+</span></span>
........
</div>



     <div *ngFor = "let i of OpenNewSchedule">
          <div  class="time-cl">
            <div class="time-ch">
              <div class="from-time" (click)="addOpentime()">
                  <input type="date" class="form-control hide-dt">
                  <span class="fdst">Open Time</span>
                  <span class="sdst">{{Opentime}}</span>
              </div>
              <div class="to-time" (click)="addCloseTime()">
                  <input type="date" class="form-control hide-dt">
                  <span class="fdst">Close Time</span>
                  <span class="sdst">{{Closetime}}</span>
              </div>
              <!-- <a  class="time-del"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></a> -->
            </div>
         </div>
       </div>
```

.ts

```
AddNewSchedule(){
for(var i =0; i<10; i++){
this.OpenNewSchedule = true;
  }
}
```

i need the div *OpenNewSchedule* to be added repeated, Now its getting added only once, and each added div have to be different value

How this can be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
public OpenNewSchedule = [];

AddNewSchedule() {
    this.OpenNewSchedule.push('some value');
}


<div *ngFor = "let i of OpenNewSchedule">
```

Comment: HI, Thank you for you reply
Getting An error
**A tuple type element list cannot be empty.**

Comment: that works fine,
issue is there is a date picker in dynamically repeated div, all that input gets same value, how could i resolve that

Comment: added the complete html section

Comment: the issue is all divs are pointing to same date picker, just check is there any id in addOpentime.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
public OpenNewSchedule = [];

AddNewSchedule() {
    this.OpenNewSchedule.push('Element');
}


<div *ngFor = "let element of OpenNewSchedule">Element to display : {{element}}</div>
```

Comment: Thank You so much, How i can get each added div with dynamic value , Now while change value in first div it get affected to all.